# Cancel remaining request when entering background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

My app has many requests and they take time to finish. When requesting, I press home button then the app enters background. I want cancel all requests so that when open the app again I can create new requests. How can I do it? Is there any standard way to do it or I'll have to cancel each service separately (ex. in willEnterBackground method)?

Comment: Use network queue to handle multiple requests..

Comment: Perhaps a quick read through of the [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html) docs is in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cancel all requests .check below Links

[iOS any way to cancel all network requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755650/ios-any-way-to-cancel-all-network-requests)

[How to immediately force cancel an NSOperation with AFNetworking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361824/how-to-immediately-force-cancel-an-nsoperation-with-afnetworking)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of getting into the complexities of managing threads you could simply keep a reference to all your active NSURLConnections. In `applicationDidEnterBackground:` cancel them:

```
for (NSURLConnection *connection in activeConnections) {
   [connection cancel];
}
```

Comment: but that way we have to create a reference array of all active connections as I have several active connections at the same time.

Comment: Right, but this is trivial.